# Best tool for converting PDF to XML-based file formats and retaining layout and styles

Tags: xml, pdf, text, pdf-generation

I've tried using Adobe Acrobat X Pro and its HTML export function is still lacking. Some text that are clearly bold are not retained. BUT I did run the document through an OCR-like tool and it was able to retain the styles within an exported word document. Then I took that word document and exported to HTML.

What are the best tools out there to easily convert PDF to HTML and retain as much as the styles and layouts?

I've heard Poppler is pretty good but haven't had sucess trying to compile it on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

`pdftohtml` from poppler - but make sure to get the latest version.